# Why do I get this at the end of a `last` command?

Tags: raspbian, last

When I run the `last` command on one of my Raspberry Pi's running Raspbian I get this at the end:

```
wtmp begins Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970
```

When I run the `last` command on a proper operating system, such as Ubuntu or Fedora I get a real date, not the epoch time. What's causing it and what does in mean (in both cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this because the `wtmp` file is rotated at the 1st of each month. (e.g. wtmp is moved to wtmp.1 and a new wtmp is created empty).

In the Raspberry PI, as you do not have a Real Time Clock to keep the time, each time you (re)boot it you are back to Epoch 0 which is Jan 1, 1970.

The good news is that you can buy an RTC (DS3231) for the Raspberry in [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-DS3231-Real-Time-Clock-Module-for-arduino-3-3V-5V-with-battery-For-Raspberry/1954150922.html) for less than 2 Euros, or in Europe for around 5-10 Euros [The Pi Hut](https://thepihut.com/products/mini-rtc-module-for-raspberry-pi?variant=758601217). I myself bought one for my Lamobo R1 and another one for my rpi 3.

see [Adding a Real Time Clock to your Raspberry Pi](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi)

As a side note, if having an Internet connection, the rpi is supposed to get back in time sometime after booting via the NTP protocol; however having an RTC means it will get back in time earlier in the bootup sequence; also the RTC is particularly handy for Raspberries/Arduinos that are not connected to the Internet.

[image: RTC]

Comment: You are welcome. While installing it can be bumpy on some rpi chinese clone boards, I can confirm it works pretty well.