# systemd: require NTP sync

Tags: systemd, ntp

What should I put in my unit file to ensure my service starts AFTER the time is set via ntp?

I have a raspberry pi with a small python script that logs data to a SQL data base. Since the rpi doesn't have an RTC battery, on startup or without an internet connection, the time and data are wrong. To avoid misleading timestamps in the database, the script should run after the correct time is acquired.

My unit file so far:

```
[Unit]
Description=desc
Requires=mysql.service
After=syslog.target mysql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart= /usr/bin/python3 /etc/script/script.py
SyslogIdentifier=test
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=syslog
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How should I modify my unit file?

My systemd version is:

```
#> systemctl --version
systemd 232
```

Comment: No, i'm stuck with what i've got for now.

Comment: a RTC battery is roughly 2 euros in aliexpress.

Comment: I don't have a raspberry pi distro to test against; my initiali instinct is to order mysql after ntp; is that sufficient?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro is a Raspberry PI. It does not have a RTC clock at all. It's a module that is sold separately and need to be plugged in (Real Time Clock RTC DS3231 GPIO Module).

Comment: @MarvinNoll, what about if you use `systemctl edit mysql.service` and add the line `After=network.target ntp.service` (note that you will need to know the exact name of your ntp service, cause it can be ntpd, openntp...), and `systemd` will create an override file at `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf` with your customizations. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @nwildner I agree....2 euros in alixepress, including the battery. ;-p

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro only thing i got to my rpi at home is a MegaPI case :) (google it) Awesomely crafted with full functional shutdown/restart buttons

Comment: @nwildner https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367949/why-do-i-get-this-at-the-end-of-a-last-command/367965#367965

Comment: @nwildner I have one with a bus extender for  using a breadboard with an official? black case, and my router is an R1 lamobo. Both have an RTC, and they used to have temperature sensors too. I also have the "official" red and white cases (chinese copies)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thats cool. shame on my country that has lot of taxes so, importing hardware is a pain :P

Answer (score 3):

Since it appears that [raspbian use timesyncd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94651), I would adjust your unit file to depend on that target:

```
[Unit]
Description=desc
Requires=mysql.service
After=syslog.target mysql.service  systemd-timesyncd.service
#                                  ^^^    the addition   ^^^

[Service]
Type=simple
...
```

If you've disabled timesyncd in favor of ntp, then substitute the NTP service name.

It [appears that newer (239+) systemd versions support a time-sync service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95195) which sounds more useful, as it waits until the clock has been synchronized, versus just the beginning of the sync process.

If a short startup time isn't critical, and you find that your service is still starting before the time has been sync'd, you may find it sufficient to add a brief delay in your service's startup with an `ExecStartPre`:

```
...
ExecStartPre=sleep 30
...
```

Adjust the sleep time based on experimentation with the time it reliably takes your pi to sync the time.