# systemd service start after network online and time synced

Tags: centos, scripting, systemd, services

I made a system service for a python script, I want it starts on boot after the server is online and the time is synced correctly.

What do I have to add in .service file?

I tried in [Unit] with requires, wants, etc. like

```
After=network-online.target time-sync.target
```

but it didn't work, it starts with time in January 1970 and not on Internet.

How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Interesting; looking back at a [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513497/117549), it sounded like time-sync.target would be the right solution. What systemd version do you have?

Comment: @JeffSchaller systemd 242 (242.29-1-manjaro). time-sync doesn't work, there is the time-sync.target file in the directory, but it doesn't work.